# window loses focus after printing shortcut (Ctrl + P) is used to print an Iframe in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, browser

I am working on a screen which contains only an iframe and within that iframe there is a table which I need to print. I used the following code to do that

```js
jQuery(window).on("keyup keydown", function(e){
      if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80){
          window.frames['tableToPrint'].focus();
          window.frames['tableToPrint'].print();
      }
   });
```

This code works the FIRST TIME ONLY. I mean, I type my url which opens the webpage and the iframe in it opens like it should. I press Ctrl + P which open the browser's print dialog box to get a PDF copy and if I go through with it I get my PDF like I want it to. After the first time whenever I try I get an empty PDF.

From debugging it looks like that once the browser's print window closes the focus from iframe is taken away and the events that I have binded afterwards are not working.

I tried

```js
var iframe = $("#tableToPrint")[0];
iframe.contentWindow.focus();
```

I tried

```
window.onafterprint = function(e) {
   $('#tableToPrint').focus();
};
```

Among other things which I could find on the net but they don't work. It behaves as if events after the print statement does not work and looks like they get lost and browser is unknown to it.

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting around a bit with this and from what I can see, it doesn't seem possible to call .print() on a non-window element, meaning your code should be throwing the following error each time it executes:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.frames.tableToPrint.print is not a function

And from what I can see, the focus doesn't matter either when printing...

so my question to you is: have you tried printing without any of your JQuery / JS code running whatsoever? Does that itself actually already provide what you desire?

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames for more info on the window.frames property.

(next response from me will be in about 16ish hours)

Comment: I'm not getting this error in my console. I think it may be a focus issue because if highlight something in the iframe then it prints everything like it should

Comment: hmm well I'm honestly not sure what to do right now as we don't seem to have similar results with our code.... whatsoever.

What browser do you use? I was using a current release of Chrome on an Ubuntu OS.